# Is it allowed for a scholarship beneficiary in Australia to earn more than a stipend?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, job, australia

I am a PhD (research sector) student with full scholarship. I normally work 4 hours every day (Mon-Fri) which means I worked for 20 hours per week and 40 hours in 2 weeks, from 7pm-11 pm shift. According to my scholarship I am only permitted to work 8 hours per week and 16 hours in 2 weeks between 9am to 5 pm.

According to recent work limitation, student can only work for 48 hours. This month my professor offer a casual research assistant position for 3 months. when I calculated my earning it would be more than 1,200 stipend i earn every week.

Because of this offer I have reduced my night shift to 16 hours per week and 32 hours in 2 weeks with addition of 16 hours from the offer granted to me in my faculty making it 48 hours in 2 weeks.
Now here are my concerns, I need clarification on the following:

1. As a PhD on research status, I think I have no work limitation but people said it is only for phd or master by research on self funding that do not have work limitation. Please kindly let me know the fact on this matter
2. The second question is that the casual research assistant salary and my second job salary together is higher than my stipend, please Is it right ? Hope I'm violating any rule?
3. Please kindly help me I need clarification urgently.

My professor is not aware that I do other job because I go to school everyday and I am making remarkable progress in my research as I have published few articles within one year of my commencement.

Thanks in anticipation of your response.

Comment: You need to check whether your visa has any work restrictions and whether your scholarship restricts you to only work for the university or related to your studies. From what I can tell masters/PhD by research students do not have any work restrictions unless their scholarship or visa has restrictions.

Comment: Your scholarship limits your work. You're exceeding those limits. I don't know how it works there, but where I'm from the penalty for that could include loss of the scholarship and even needing to pay back what you already received.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you for your comment. Here is the condition on my visa: The 48-hour requirement does not apply if:

● you are the holder of a Student visa granted in relation to a masters degree by research or doctoral degree and you have commenced the masters degree or doctoral degree.  According to visa 48 hours are allowed but for the school 16 hours are allowed in 2 weeks. All together I am within 48 hours. I maintain 8 hours per week within 9am to 5pm, while i do shift from 7pm to 11pm night. My concern is about the income  if there is rule not to earn above the stipend